# Вызов функции с аргументом {}?

Tags: javascript

Помогите понять пример, а именно: что это за вызов функции с первым аргументом в виде фигурных скобок? Это в аргумент передаёт объект, или что-то типа того?(можно даже ссылкой где почитать про такое).

Про само движение элемента по окружности вроде как все понятно. Единственно что интересно, как бы задать в функции, чтоб центр окружности находился в центре элемента. Наверное `this.offsetX, У`?

Вызывают в примере функцию так:

```
<div class="css" onClick="animation({}, this);"></div>
```

Сама функция (комментарии в функции не мои):

```
function animation(args, elem) { // некоторые аргументы определим на будущее
    var $ = {
        radius  :     250, // радиус окружности 
        speed   :     20 // скорость/задержка ( в js это мс, например 10 мс = 100 кадров в секунду)
    }
    var f = 0;
    var s = 2 * Math.PI / 180; //Вычислим угол
    setInterval(function() { // функция движения 
        f += s; // приращение аргумента
          elem.style.left =  235 + $.radius * Math.sin(f)  + 'px'; // меняем координаты элемента, подобно тому как мы это делали в школе в декартовой системе координат. Правда, в данном случае используется полярная система координат, изменяя угол
          elem.style.top =   235 + $.radius * Math.cos(f) + 'px';
    }, $.speed)
}
```

Comment: если добавите рабочий пример кода, на jsfiddle например, дополню ответ про центр окружности. Если центр окружности будет находиться в центре элемента, то как он будет по ней двигаться?

Comment: С мобильного это очень сложно, рабочий комп не пускает на разные такие сайты. Потому и ошибки в форматирования. Центр окружности то будет браться относительно координат центра элемента, но двигаться элемент то будет по окружности.

Comment: Когда появится возможность - дополните, и я обновлю ответ

Answer (score 4):

Да, в этом случае передается, новый пустой объект.

Подробнее можно почитать в справке: [литерал object](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#.D0.9B.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BB_object)

> Литерал object — это список из **нуля** или более пар, состоящих из имен свойств и связанных с ними значений, заключенный в фигурные скобки ( {} ).
>   Вам не следует использовать литерал object в начале выражения, т.к. это приведет к ошибке или к поведению, которого вы не ожидаете, потому что символ "{" будет интерпретироваться как начало блока.